# divs are sorting by price upto 4 digits but with 5 digits sorting does not happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

i have a search result page on which results are being displayed. i have implemented https://jsfiddle.net/f8w1hpj2/2/ this code for sorting.

everything works fine with name sorting. but with price sorting if the prices are 1000, 2000, 2500, 3000 ( only 4 digits ) sorting works.
but if the prices are like 2000, 3000, 4000, 9000, 11000 then sorting in descending order doesnt happen.

it shows 9000, 4000, 3000, 2000 & then 11000.

html
    
     Sort by Price:
Sort by Name:

```
    <div id= "row" class="row">
        <div id="items" class="col-md-7">
        <div class="clist">
            <div data-sid="2000" data-name="c">
                <a href="www.example.com?id=1">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                        <div>
                            Name:
                            <h1>C</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>Price:2000</div>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div data-sid="3000" data-name="a">
                <a href="www.example.com?id=2">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                        <div>
                            Name:
                            <h1>A</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>Price:3000</div>

                    </div>
                </a>
                </div>
            <div data-sid="11000" data-name="b">
                <a href="www.example.com?id=3">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                        <div>
                            Name:
                            <h1>B</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>Price:11000</div>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#price').on('click', function(){
    var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
    if(s === 0){
        $(this).data('sort', 1);
        $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
           return a.dataset.sid < b.dataset.sid
        }).appendTo('.clist')            
    }else{
        $(this).data('sort', 0);
        $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
           return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid
        }).appendTo('.clist')
    }
});

    $('#name').on('click', function(){
    var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
    if(s === 0){
        $(this).data('sort', 1);
        $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
           return a.dataset.name < b.dataset.name
        }).appendTo('.clist')            
    }else{
        $(this).data('sort', 0);
        $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
           return a.dataset.name > b.dataset.name
        }).appendTo('.clist')
    }
});
```

});

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you're sorting as strings, and `'1' < '9'` is TRUE. You need to conver those strings to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sorting strings, not numbers.

```
$('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt(a.dataset.sid, 10) > parseInt(b.dataset.sid, 10);
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

subtracting should work as well

```
$('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
    return a.dataset.sid - b.dataset.sid;
});
```

Comment: i have price range slider on the same page which refreshes result via ajax without refreshing the page. now after the range slider is used i am unable to sort by price and name. it shows an error on line  var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);

Comment: Post it as a new question, it shouldn't really be related to the sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is tha you are comparing the values as strings, convert them to numbers, for example...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#price').on('click', function(){
        var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
        if(s === 0){
            $(this).data('sort', 1);
            $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
               return parseInt(a.dataset.sid) < parseInt(b.dataset.sid)
            }).appendTo('.clist')            
        }else{
            $(this).data('sort', 0);
            $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
               return parseInt(a.dataset.sid) > parseInt(b.dataset.sid)
            }).appendTo('.clist')
        }
    });

        $('#name').on('click', function(){
        var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
        if(s === 0){
            $(this).data('sort', 1);
            $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.name < b.dataset.name
            }).appendTo('.clist')            
        }else{
            $(this).data('sort', 0);
            $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.name > b.dataset.name
            }).appendTo('.clist')
        }
    });
});
```